# Mouse click vs jquery click vs dispatchEvent click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, mouseevent

Can someone explain to me why **actual mouse click**
and **$('div').click()** runs click event 3 times while **$('div')[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))** runs click event only 1 time according to browser console?

Here's a simple html code:

```
<div>test</div>
```

Here's a javascript code:

```
$('*').click(function(e){
   console.log(e); 
});

var c = new MouseEvent('click');

// Actual mouse click output event 3 times
//$('div').click(); // output event 3 times
$('div')[0].dispatchEvent(c); // output event 1 time
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5uvjwa4t/2/

Thanks

Comment: Because in `dispatchEvent` you specified a `div` and in `click` you select all using `*` (including html & body) tags + div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asterisk matches the `<html>` and `<body` tags as well, and as click events bubble it's fired on three elements when you use the asterisk as a selector for the event handler.

```
$('*') // matches all elements, including html and body

$('div') // matches the DIV only
```

When you fire a click on a div that is nested like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
```

The click travels up (bubbles) and fires on all parent elements as well.

Using `dispatchEvent` fires the event three times for me in Chrome, but there could be differences in other browsers.
To make it consistently bubble the `bubbles` setting can be set, that way it will behave as a regular click and bubble up.

```
var c = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles:true});
```

Comment: Great, **{bubbles: true}** this is what I was looking for!