# How do I programmatically trigger keypress event on an input, on mouseleave in angular 2?

Tags: angular

How do I programmatically trigger keypress event on an input on mouseleave in angular 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 manually firing click event on particular element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639486/angular2-manually-firing-click-event-on-particular-element)

Comment: firing key events are a bit different then firing a click