# Angular2 How to subscribe to event in Component code?

Tags: angular

I have a `[boolean]` directive with an `Output` event:

```ts
@Output() booleanChanged = new EventEmitter();
...
this.booleanChanged.emit(value);
```

And in my view:

```ts
<input type="checkbox" [boolean] (booleanChanged)="updateBoolean()"/>
```

I would like to subscribe to this event from the component's code and not in the view.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Output()` events can only be used by `(myoutput)="..."` bindings.

You could emit a custom DOM event. DOM events bubble and can be listened to from parent components

```ts
class BooleanDirective {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef){}

  emitEvent() {
    final event = new CustomEvent('mycustomevent', {detail: 'abc', bubbles : true});
    this.elRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event)
  }
}
```

```ts
@HostListener('mycustomevent', ['$event'])
myCustomEventHandler(event) {
  ...
}
```

See also [angular2 manually firing click event on particular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639486/angular2-manually-firing-click-event-on-particular-element/36639596#36639596)

Comment: Is there a way to share this custom event in multiple directives?

Comment: What do you mean with "share" exactly?

Comment: I want to fire the same event from multiple directives (and subscribe once) is it enough to just use the same name like 'mycustomevent'?

Comment: Exactly. It's only about the event name string to match.

Comment: Sorry about that. You can just use `var`. I'm sure it will work. I don't use TypeScript myself, but expected it to work.

Comment: "not working" is pretty vague. Do you get an error message?

Comment: It works when I set the `bubbles` property of the `CustomEventInit` to true

Comment: I assumed it bubbles by default (didn't actually check). If it doesn't, then yes, you need to set it.

Comment: @naomi thanks a lot for your feedback and the edit :)