# angular programmatically click input from ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639596/6656422 this works for buttons but not ngAfterViewInit.

In this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/p4jsdPR9varhV9ihUhO5?p=preview `fileInputElement.click();` opens the browser file prompt when called from the button click but not from `ngAfterViewInit` even though `fileInputElement` is defined.

Edit: I'v tried NgZone.run() and setTimeout(), without luck.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the down vote?

Comment: I recommend you to check docs, in good projects you can manipulate the functionality programmatically.

Comment: I am familiar with the angular documentation, but it sounds like you know something I don't. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't you use a third party library? It seemed to me that you do. If it's native angular, sorry, i have no idea how to help you =(