# Typescript error with Angular 5 and FullCalendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I followed all steps given in [fullcalendar & Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950588/fullcalendar-angular-5) to set up FullCalendar with Angular 5 project (new project, nothing else added after `ng new`)

While trying to run `ng serve` command, I'm getting following errors (& many more)

```
ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-03-05T14:44:41.420Z
Hash: 33eefe59976d9e67375d
Time: 3084ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 577 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js (scripts) 456 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 113 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 852 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/fullcalendar- scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(60,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'dayIDs'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(61,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'unitsDesc'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(94,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(98,2): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(110,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(119,2): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(123,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(142,2): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(146,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(160,2): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(163,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'globalDefaults'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(223,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'englishDefaults'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(226,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'rtlDefaults'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(248,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(253,2): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(261,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(267,2): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'default'.
node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(272,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Default'.
```

What am I missing and how to solve these `Duplicate identifier` errors?

Comment: rather than anything being missing the word "duplicate" strongly suggests that something is being included more than once...

Comment: Yes, but that is in node_modules, not the code written by me. This is not supposed to happen like that thus I'm assuming I did something wrong in configuration/installation. Just couldn't understand what?

Comment: Removing fullcalendar-schedular solves the issue. Fullcalendar-schedular is also having fullcalendar in its dependencies, which was causing issues.

Comment: Ok that's useful to know. If you don't need Scheduler you can certainly remove it. If you do want to use Scheduler, I guess you install just that and not the main fullCalendar package as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing fullcalendar-schedular solves the issue. Fullcalendar-schedular is also having fullcalendar in its dependencies, which was causing issues.

Comment: If you look at the actual package.json in the sample app from the tutorial, it shows different package versions. Thise will work. Also, what if someone needs schedular?

Answer (score 1):

The **fullcalendar-scheduler** version in the package.json file may be preceded with some ~ or ^ symbols which may install the incompatible version with the **fullcalender** installed in you machine. So specify the exact compatible version for the fullcalendar-scheduler in the packag.json file and also make sure that the installed version is same as we specified in the package.json file by using **npm list** command.

Answer (score -1):

Only set setting "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json this solved my problem.
Good luck.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
}
```