# Angular 5 - generate click event from component

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to generate click event from within component on some condition.
In AngularJs, I used to do:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#someid')).click();
```

In Angular 2/4/5, I found **ElementRef** which is not recommended. They say, use renderer, but found no such example to generate click event.

How can do this in Angular 2/4/5?

Comment: I'd advise to not do this but rather call the event handler that click would call on a click. If you have a need to trigger from the element due to other plugins try calling the plug-in events that would happen on click. Like dropdown.expand() etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 manually firing click event on particular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639486/angular2-manually-firing-click-event-on-particular-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the renderer2 listen method. This can be done with the following line:

```
constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
    renderer.listen(el.nativeElement, 'click', event => console.log(event));
  }
```

https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

If you need to get an exact element within the template file you can create a reference using **#someid**

Then in the .ts file use:

```
 @ViewChild('someid) someid: ElementRef
```

Then use it once again with the renderer2 passing **someid.nativeElement**

Hope this helps!

Another alternative is to use: https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener