# Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type '() => void' in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, click, angular2-forms

I want to trigger a click event even without clicking on the button. So I followed the structure mentioned in the post - 
[angular2 manually firing click event on particular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639486/angular2-manually-firing-click-event-on-particular-element/36639596)

However, I am getting an error:

```
Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type '() => void'
```

for which I find no relevant reference in the web.

I want to trigger the showAccurateGraphs() button on clicking on accurateExtract().

My code is -

**app.component.html**

```
<button type="button"   (click)="accurateExtract()" class="btn btn-
dark">Accurate Extract</button>

 <button type="button" #accurateExt (click)="showAccurateGraphs()" 
   class="btn btn-dark">Show Accurate API Graph</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

   import {  ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core'


   constructor(private renderer:Renderer ) {}

   @ViewChild('accurateExt') accurateExt: ElementRef;


   accurateExtract(){


    let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
    this.accurateExtract.nativeElement,'dispatchEvent', [event]);

     }
```

Comment: Check that post SO answer you referred. It says instead of invokeElementMethod() use dispatchEvent() method. Also use Renderer2. Renderer is deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2 manually firing click event on particular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639486/angular2-manually-firing-click-event-on-particular-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follow, because `invokeElementMethod()` is no more available in [renderer API](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) 2 in angular. there's a spelling mistake in your property, you should change `this.accurateExtract` to `this.accurateExt`

```
 accurateExtract(){
    let event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
    this.accurateExt.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Bear . But still i get the error - Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type '() => void'.

Comment: When will this function gets called?

Comment: when i click on accurateExtract() button, i would like showAccurateGraphs() to be called.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. `accurateExt` use this property

Comment: Ok thank you. But i get error - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Actually, what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to automate the showAccurateGraphs() click button. I want that once the accurateExtract() button is clicked, the showAccurateGraphs() button to trigger automatically

Comment: showAccurateGraphs() is this method created inside your component.ts

Comment: `accurateExtract(){ this.showAccurateGraphs (); }` if the showaccurategraphs methos is in your component.ts you can use this way to trigger the function

Comment: no actually, this.showAccurateGraphs(), when i call inside accurateExtract() , i get an error - 'hasChildNodes' of null ... it is a javascript graph error , where there is issue with the onload event trigger. I haven't understood it exactly. I have to look deep into it. But i thought maybe triggering the click button may work.

Comment: can you share us the code inside `showAccurateGraphs()` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189104/discussion-between-bear-nithi-and-techdive).